# Objective C Loop

Tags: objective-c, loops, while-loop

I am trying to loop this code until the yser types in DONE. I used the while loop but only parts of the embedded while loop is executed. Why is the first prompt(Enter the name) not executing in the following program? Thanks

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int number;
    int i = 1;
    double payRate, hours, totalPay;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *amount;
    char inputBuffer[200];

    NSNumberFormatter *price = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [price setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [price setCurrencySymbol:@"$"]; 

    while(i > 0){
        NSLog (@"Enter the name:");
        scanf("%[^\n]", inputBuffer);
        name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:inputBuffer];

        if([name isEqualToString:@"DONE"])
            break;
        else{
            NSLog (@"Enter the total number of hours: ");
            scanf ("%lf", &hours);

            NSLog (@"Enter the pay rate: ");
            scanf ("%lf", &payRate);

            if(hours <= 40)
                totalPay = hours * payRate;
            else
                totalPay = 400 + (payRate * (hours - 40) * 1.5);

            NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",totalPay];

            NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[myString doubleValue]];
            amount = [price stringFromNumber:myNumber];

            NSLog(@"Name: %@", name);
            NSLog(@"Hours:%.2lf", hours);
            NSLog(@"Pay Rate:%.2lf",payRate);
            NSLog(@"Total Pay:%@", amount);

            NSLog(@"\n");
        }

    }

    NSLog (@"DONE!");

   }
```

Comment: what does "not executing" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be contributed to a number of buffering issues, such as `scanf()`ing numbers, but not the following line feeds. On top of this, I sometimes find that `NSLog()` messes of stdin/stdout buffering if you are also using `printf()` or `scanf()`. Usually I find it best to avoid the `scanf()` function whenever possible, especially when using a higher-level language like Objective-C.

Instead of using `scanf()` to read user input, I wrote a small function to read a line from the console, and return it as an `NSString`. This function looks as follows:

```
NSString * readLine (FILE * input) {
    NSMutableString * string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    int aChar = 0;
    while ((aChar = fgetc(input)) != EOF) {
        if (aChar != '\r') {
            if (aChar == '\n') {
                break;
            } else if (aChar > 0) {
                [string appendFormat:@"%C", aChar];
            }
        }
    }
    return [string autorelease];
}
```

Using this, you could rewrite your `main()` function using this new method. In the following code I have also taken out all `NSLog()` statements that prompt the user for information, replacing them with more appropriate `printf()` calls.

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    double payRate, hours, totalPay;
    NSString * name;
    NSString * amount;

    NSNumberFormatter * price = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [price setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [price setCurrencySymbol:@"$"]; 

    while (YES) {
        printf("Please, enter your name: ");
        name = readLine(stdin);

        if ([name isEqualToString:@"DONE"])
            break;
        else {
            printf("Enter the total number of hours: ");
            hours = [readLine(stdin) intValue];

            printf("Enter the pay rate: ");
            payRate = [readLine(stdin) intValue];

            if (hours <= 40)
                totalPay = hours * payRate;
            else
                totalPay = 400 + (payRate * (hours - 40) * 1.5);

            NSNumber * myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:totalPay];
            amount = [price stringFromNumber:myNumber];

            NSLog(@"Name: %@", name);
            NSLog(@"Hours: %.2lf", hours);
            NSLog(@"Pay Rate: %.2lf",payRate);
            NSLog(@"Total Pay: %@", amount);
        }
    }

    [price release];
    NSLog(@"DONE!");

    [pool drain];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In: `scanf("%[^\n]", inputBuffer);` that does not read anything from the user, you need to read from the user into `inputBuffer`.

Also NSLog is not a good way to send text to the user, probably use "C" functions since you are writing a "C" program.